# Woocommerce allow html in short description on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding short description (excerpts) of a product on the category page but I can't get the html tags in the excerpts to work. Strangely they work in the single product page. Given below is the function I'm using, just in case. I'm using `understrap` theme framework for wordpress.

```
function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->post->post_excerpt ) return;
    ?>
    <div itemprop="description">
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt ) ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description', 5);
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
<p>lorem lipsum losem</p>
```

This is the output that I desire (this is what I've added in the short description box on woocommerce product backend):

```
<ul>
    <li> lorem </li>
    <li> lipsum </li>
    <li> losem </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? What is the desired output?

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ( array( 'pre_term_description' ) as $filter ) {
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_filter_kses' );
}

foreach ( array( 'term_description' ) as $filter ) {
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_kses_data' );
}
```

Try by adding this snippet to your active child theme's functions.php